# Using extended euclidean algorithm to find number of intersections of a line segment with points on a 2D grid

Tags: algorithm, discrete-mathematics, greatest-common-divisor, number-theory

In the grid constructed by grid points (M*x, M*y) and given the point A(x1,y1) and point B(x2,y2) where all the variables are integers. I need to check how many grid points lie on the line segment from point A to point B. I know that it can be done by using the extended euclidean algorithm somehow, but I have no clue on how to do it. I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rephrased, you want to determine how many numbers `t` satisfy

```
(1) M divides (1-t) x1 + t x2
(2) M divides (1-t) y1 + t y2
(3) 0 <= t <= 1.
```

Let's focus on `(1)`. We introduce an integer variable `q` to represent the divisibility constraint and solve for `t`:

```
exists integer q,  M q = (1-t) x1 + t x2

exists integer q,  M q - x1 = (x2 - x1) t.
```

If `x1` is not equal to `x2`, then this gives a periodic set of possibilities of the form `t in {a + b q | q integer}`, where `a` and `b` are fractions. Otherwise, all `t` or no `t` are solutions.

The extended Euclidean algorithm is useful for intersecting the solution sets arising from `(1)` and `(2)`. Suppose that we want to compute the intersection

```
{a + b q | q integer} intersect {c + d s | s integer}.
```

By expressing a generic common element in two different ways, we arrive at a [linear Diophantine equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation#Linear_Diophantine_equations):

```
a + b q = c + d s,
```

where `a, b, c, d` are constant and `q, s` are integer. Let's clear denominators and gather terms into one equation

```
A q + B s = C,
```

where `A, B, C` are integers. This equation has solutions if and only if the greatest common divisor `g` of `A` and `B` also divides `C`. Use the extended Euclidean algorithm to compute integer coefficients `u, v` such that

```
A u + B v = g.
```

Then we have a solution

```
q = u (C/g) + k (B/g)
s = v (C/g) - k (A/g)
```

for each integer `k`.

Finally, we have to take constraint `(3)` into consideration. This should boil down to some arithmetic and one floor division, but I'd rather not work out the details (the special cases of what I've written so far already will take quite a lot of your time).

Answer (score 0):

Let's `dX = Abs(x2-x1)` and `dY = Abs(y2 - y1)`
Then number of lattice points on the segment is

```
P = GCD(dX, dY) + 1
```

(including start and end points)
where GCD is the greatest common divisor (through usual (not extended) Euclidean algorithm)

(See last Properties [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor#Properties))

Answer (score 0):

Following instructions of Mr. David Eisenstat I have managed to write a program in c++ that calculates the answer.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int gcd (int A, int B, int &u, int &v)
{
int Ad = 1;
int Bd = 1;
if (A < 0) { Ad = -1; A = -A; }
if (B < 0) { Bd = -1; B = -B; }

int x = 1, y = 0;
u = 0, v = 1;

while (A != 0)
{
    int q = B/A;
    int r = B%A;
    int m = u-x*q;
    int n = v-y*q;
    B = A;
    A = r;
    u = x;
    v = y;
    x = m;
    y = n;
}

u *= Ad;
v *= Bd;

return B;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
int t;
scanf("%d", &t);

for (int i = 0; i<t; i++) {

    int x1, x2, y1, y2, M;

    scanf("%d %d %d %d %d", &M, &x1, &y1, &x2, &y2);

    if ( x1 == x2 ) // vertical line
    {
        if (x1%M != 0) { // in between the horizontal lines
            cout << 0 << endl;
        } else
        {
            int r = abs((y2-y1)/M); // number of points
            if (y2%M == 0 || y1%M == 0) // +1 if the line starts or ends on the point
                r++;

            cout << r << endl;
        }

    } else {

        if (x2 < x1)
        {
            int c;
            c = x1;
            x1 = x2;
            x2 = c;
        }

        int A, B, C;

        C = x1*y2-y1*x2;
        A = M*(y2-y1);
        B = -M*(x2-x1);

        int u, v;
        int g = gcd(A, B, u, v);

        //cout << "A: " << A << " B: " << B << " C: " << C << endl;
        //cout << A << "*" << u <<"+"<< B <<"*"<<v<<"="<<g<<endl;

        double a = -x1/(double)(x2-x1);
        double b = M/(double)(x2-x1);

        double Z = (-a-C*b/g*u)*g/(B*b);
        double Y = (1-a-C*b/g*u)*g/(B*b);

        cout << floor(Z) - ceil(Y) + 1 << endl;
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

Thank you for your help! Please check if all special cases are taken into consideration.